# Pushing a View on a Different View with Result from Another View

Tags: iphone

I am creating a simple program where there is a main view which has a segmented control and a logo and some blank space. When the user clicks a segment of the Segmented Control, a view comes up just below the Segmented Control which has 6 buttons that leads user to different views.

I want that the view that appears right after the user clicks the button should not appear on the view where the buttons are (which it will if I use that "addSubView" option). Instead, I want the view to appear on the whole screen which means I want the resultant view (after clicking the button) to appear on the main view.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your asking is: Is there a way that the subview can tell my mainView to add a new view. This can be done by delegation, singletons or notifications. I would suggest using a simple notification:

```
// This is your observer listening for the notification named @"LaunchViewOne"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LaunchViewOne) name:@"LaunchViewOne" object:nil];

// This is supplying the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LaunchViewOne" object:nil];
```

So when your button is pressed use postNotification.

Answer (score 1):

You can create property for all the controls that you need to access outside of its own class. Then you can access it as below:

```
Class c = [[Class alloc] init];
someValue = c.mypropery;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UINavigationController. When the user click on one of the six buttons, you can use the pushViewController:animated: to navigate to the new view. By default, this will also give you a navigation bar at the top of the screen allow the user to go back. If you don't want that, you can turn that off though.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question, but you can use a lot of methods to manage views hierarchy

```
– addSubview:
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `addSubView:`, just that you don't want to do `[viewWhereYouHaveButtons addSubView:someView]`, but `[yourMainView addSubView:someView]`.